# bulk insert data into table where cell can be empty string for a column that is part of a composite primary key, using psycopg3

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, psycopg3

I have the following table - note there is a composite primary key consisting of 5 columns.

```
test_ts = Table('test_ts', meta,
    Column('metric_id', ForeignKey('metric.id'), primary_key = True), 
    Column('entity_id', Integer, primary_key = True), 
    Column('date', DateTime, primary_key = True),              
    Column('freq', String, primary_key = True),           
    Column('context', String, primary_key = True, server_default=""),
    Column('value', String),
    Column("update_time", DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.current_timestamp()),
    Column('update_by', String, server_default=func.current_user()))
```

I am trying to bulk insert some data into this POSTGRES table, but where the 'context' column may be an empty string (''):

```
                       date context  value freq  entity_id  metric_id
1  1999-02-01T05:00:00.000Z    test    101    D       1105          4
2  1999-02-02T05:00:00.000Z    test    102    D       1105          4
8  1999-02-01T05:00:00.000Z            201    D       1105          4
9  1999-02-02T05:00:00.000Z            202    D       1105          4
```

When trying to do this however, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/service/data_svc.py", line 121, in bulk_insert
    cur.execute(sql_insert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg/cursor.py", line 732, in execute
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
psycopg.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "context" of relation "test_ts" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 1105, 1999-02-01 05:00:00, D, null, 201, 2024-03-27 21:23:42.778517, db_user).
```

**You can see above, the row value contains a 'null' when it should be an empty string.**
I am not sure why the empty string is getting converted to null here - as it's not None or Nan, but explictly set to '' in my pandas dataframe.

The SQL im using are the following:

```
sql_create:
drop table if exists tmp_tbl; CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE tmp_tbl AS SELECT date,context,value,freq,entity_id,metric_id FROM test_ts LIMIT 0

sql_copy:
COPY tmp_tbl (date,context,value,freq,entity_id,metric_id) FROM STDIN (FORMAT CSV,  DELIMITER "\t")

sql_insert:
insert into test_ts(date,context,value,freq,entity_id,metric_id) 
select * from tmp_tbl on conflict(metric_id,entity_id,date,freq,context) 
do update set value = EXCLUDED.value;drop table if exists tmp_tbl;
```

and the code snippet looks like this:

```
      with psycopg.connect(self.connect_str, autocommit=True) as conn:
         io_buf = io.StringIO()
         df.to_csv(io_buf, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
         io_buf.seek(0)
         
         with conn.cursor() as cur:
               cur.execute(sql_create)
               with cur.copy(sql_copy) as copy:
                  while data:=io_buf.read(self.batch_size):
                     copy.write(data)

               cur.execute(sql_insert)
         conn.commit()
```

I can work around this by using something like 'N/A' instead of ''...but would much prefer it to be an empty string.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` to your `.to_csv()` call.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesnt work. adding this results in ```Exception has occurred: InvalidTextRepresentation       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: ts_upload)
invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""```

Comment: im guessing it is because this code is also used to upload to a table where value is a float as well as the above table where it is a varchar

Comment: i did test it on the string column above and it does not cause the error, but also, it seems to silently ignore the rows that are that have an empty 'context' value- they are never inserted into the table.

Comment: [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *NULL Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format.*